# How to install ipywidgets offline (from file)

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

So I am trying to install ipywidgets-0.0.1 into my Anaconda environment. I am running Anaconda3. Unfortunately, the machine I need to install it on does not have internet access.

The basic way to install the package is to run `conda install ipywidgets`, but of course this gives the following error:

```
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/p
ro/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
...
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment C:\Program Files\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    ipywidgets-0.0.1           |       np19py34_0           7 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ipywidgets: 0.0.1-np19py34_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Fetching packages ...
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/ipywidgets-0.0.1
-np19py34_0.tar.bz2
Error: Connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.continuum.io', port=443)
: Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/win-64/ipywidgets-0.0.1-np19py34_0.t
ar.bz2 (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddri
nfo failed'))): 
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/ipywidgets-0.0.1-np19py34_0.tar.bz2
```

This makes sense, since the box can't access the internet.
I downloaded the ipywidgets tarball from the listed URL at https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/ipywidgets-0.0.1-np19py34_0.tar.bz2, and I ssh'ed it onto the box.

What command can I run on the box (it is a Windows 7 environment) so that it will run the install as local, looking at the downloaded tarball to unpack rather than trying to access the internet to get the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the whole package **and its dependencies** to some local directory
You can get it from PYPI [ipywidgets](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipywidgets)

Let's consider you donwloaded from PYPI and you have `~/src/ipywidgets` with `~/src/ipywidgets/setup.py` which will have `install_requires` with a list of dep. in your `/pypi` directory. Like so:

`install_requires=['hello', 'etc', ...]`

To install your app and its dep. into the current python env., you've to do something like:

```
$ cd ~/src/ipywidgets
$ easy_install --always-unzip --allow-hosts=None --find-links=/pypi
```

Note that the build will fail if one or more dependencies are missing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `conda` for this, might as well if you are already using anaconda, you should also be able to do:

```
conda install --offline PATH_TO_FILE/ipywidgets-0.0.1-np19py34_0.tar.bz2
```

Where, of course, `PATH_TO_FILE` is just the path to the file you've downloaded.